# How to rearrange views in SwiftUI ZStack by dragging

Tags: swift, swiftui, draggable

How can I rearrange a view's position in a ZStack by dragging it above or below another view (e.g. in this instance how can I rearrange the order of the cards in the deck by dragging a card above or below another card, to move the dragged card behind or in front of said card in deck).

I want for the card to change indices when dragged up or down in the stack and fluidly appear behind each and every card in the stack as it is dragged- and stay there on mouse up.

*Summary:* In other words, the card dragged and the cards above it should switch as I drag up and the card dragged and the cards below it should switch as I drag down.

I figure this has something to do with changing the ZStack order in `struct CardView: View` and updating the position from inside `DragGesture().onChanged` by evaluating how much the card has been dragged (perhaps by viewing the self.offset value) but I have not been able to work out how to do this in a reliable way.

Here's what I have right now:

[image: drawing]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

let cardSpace:CGFloat = 10

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cardColors: [Color] = [.orange, .green, .yellow, .purple, .red, .orange, .green, .yellow, .purple]
    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    CardView(colors: self.$cardColors)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .position(x: 370, y: 300)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State var dragging:Bool = false
    @State var tapped:Bool = false
    @State var tappedLocation:Int = -1
    @Binding var colors: [Color]
    @State var locationDragged:Int = -1
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<self.colors.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    ColorCard(reader:reader, i:i, colors: self.$colors, offset: self.$offset, tappedLocation: self.$tappedLocation, locationDragged:self.$locationDragged, tapped: self.$tapped, dragging: self.$dragging)
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.spring())
    }
}

struct ColorCard: View {
    var reader: GeometryProxy
    var i:Int
    @State var offsetHeightBeforeDragStarted: Int = 0
    @Binding var colors: [Color]
    @Binding var offset: CGSize
    @Binding var tappedLocation:Int
    @Binding var locationDragged:Int
    @Binding var tapped:Bool
    @Binding var dragging:Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
            VStack {
                self.colors[i]
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            .cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 20)
            .offset(
                x: (self.locationDragged == i) ? CGFloat(i) * self.offset.width / 14
                    : 0,
                y: (self.locationDragged == i) ? CGFloat(i) * self.offset.height / 4
                    : 0
            )
            .offset(
                x: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation != i) ? 100 : 0,
                y: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation != i) ? 0 : 0
            )
            .position(x: reader.size.width / 2, y: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation == i) ? -(cardSpace * CGFloat(i)) + 0 : reader.size.height / 2)
            }
                .rotationEffect(
                    (i % 2 == 0) ? .degrees(-0.2 * Double(arc4random_uniform(15)+1) ) : .degrees(0.2 * Double(arc4random_uniform(15)+1) )
                )

                .onTapGesture() { //Show the card
                    self.tapped.toggle()
                    self.tappedLocation = self.i
            }

            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        self.locationDragged = self.i
                        self.offset = gesture.translation
                        self.dragging = true
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    self.locationDragged = -1 //Reset
                    self.offset = .zero
                    self.dragging = false
                    self.tapped = false //enable drag to dismiss
                    self.offsetHeightBeforeDragStarted = Int(self.offset.height)
                }
            )
        }.offset(y: (cardSpace * CGFloat(i)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out:

the "trick" is that you just need to reorder the z order of the items. therefore you have to "hold" the cards in an array.

```
let cardSpace:CGFloat = 10

struct Card : Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }


    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    var id = UUID()

    var intID : Int

    static let cardColors: [Color] = [.orange, .green, .yellow, .purple, .red, .orange, .green, .yellow, .purple]

    var zIndex : Int
    var color : Color
}

class Data: ObservableObject {

    @Published var cards : [Card] = []

    init() {
        for i in 0..<Card.cardColors.count {
            cards.append(Card(intID: i, zIndex: i, color: Card.cardColors[i]))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var data : Data = Data()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                CardView().environmentObject(data)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
     //   .position(x: 370, y: 300)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var data : Data

    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State var dragging:Bool = false
    @State var tapped:Bool = false
    @State var tappedLocation:Int = -1
    @State var locationDragged:Int = -1
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(self.data.cards, id: \.self) { card in
                    ColorCard(card: card, reader:reader, offset: self.$offset, tappedLocation: self.$tappedLocation, locationDragged:self.$locationDragged, tapped: self.$tapped, dragging: self.$dragging)
                        .environmentObject(self.data)
                        .zIndex(Double(card.zIndex))
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.spring())
    }
}

struct ColorCard: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var data : Data

    var card: Card

    var reader: GeometryProxy
    @State var offsetHeightBeforeDragStarted: Int = 0
    @Binding var offset: CGSize
    @Binding var tappedLocation:Int
    @Binding var locationDragged:Int
    @Binding var tapped:Bool
    @Binding var dragging:Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                VStack {
                    card.color
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                .cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 20)
                .offset(
                    x: (self.locationDragged == card.intID) ? CGFloat(card.zIndex) * self.offset.width / 14
                        : 0,
                    y: (self.locationDragged == card.intID) ? CGFloat(card.zIndex) * self.offset.height / 4
                        : 0
                )
                    .offset(
                        x: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation != card.intID) ? 100 : 0,
                        y: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation != card.intID) ? 0 : 0
                )
                    .position(x: reader.size.width / 2, y: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation == card.intID) ? -(cardSpace * CGFloat(card.zIndex)) + 0 : reader.size.height / 2)
            }
            .rotationEffect(
                (card.zIndex % 2 == 0) ? .degrees(-0.2 * Double(arc4random_uniform(15)+1) ) : .degrees(0.2 * Double(arc4random_uniform(15)+1) )
            )

                .onTapGesture() { //Show the card
                    self.tapped.toggle()
                    self.tappedLocation = self.card.intID
            }

            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in

                        self.locationDragged = self.card.intID
                        self.offset = gesture.translation

                        if self.offset.height > 60 ||
                        self.offset.height < -60 {
                            withAnimation {

                                if let index = self.data.cards.firstIndex(of: self.card) {
                                    self.data.cards.remove(at: index)
                                    self.data.cards.append(self.card)

                                    for index in 0..<self.data.cards.count {
                                        self.data.cards[index].zIndex = index
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        self.dragging = true
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    self.locationDragged = -1 //Reset
                    self.offset = .zero
                    self.dragging = false
                    self.tapped = false //enable drag to dismiss
                    self.offsetHeightBeforeDragStarted = Int(self.offset.height)
                }
            )
        }.offset(y: (cardSpace * CGFloat(card.zIndex)))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(Data())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just drag the 2nd or 3rd-> it drags always the card you draw to the top

Comment: Sorry, I mean how can I slide cards to any place in the stack?

Comment: any place? so how will you do this by dragging? how should the user know in which place the dragging should be?

Comment: you can change                                     self.data.cards.append(self.card) to insert(at...) then the card will be inserted at the place you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea (cause requires re-think/re-code your solution). Reorder in your case needs usage/modification of card `zIndex` so it needs to be stored somewhere.

Thus instead of directly use color as model you needed more explicit model object

```
struct Card {
   var color: Color
   var deckOrder: Int
}
```

***Note:*** below is in pseudo-code, you have to adapt it yourself

next, you keep and iterate by cards (and I would separate them info ObsesrvableObject view model)

```
ForEach(Array(vm.cards.enumerated()), id: \.element) { i, card in
    ColorCard(reader:reader, i:i, cards: self.$vm.cards, 
              offset: self.$offset, tappedLocation: self.$tappedLocation, 
              locationDragged:self.$locationDragged, tapped: self.$tapped, 
              dragging: self.$dragging)
      .zIndex(card.deckOrder)
}
```

now changing `card.deckOrder` on drag you will change zIndex of view/card in deck.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Chris's answer I have come up with this.
Some shortcomings are: it requires one drag per movement versus one drag to move up or down the deck indefinitely.

Demo:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

let cardSpace:CGFloat = 10 + 20

struct Card : Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }


    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    var id = UUID()

    var intID : Int

    static let cardColors: [Color] = [.orange, .green, .yellow, .purple, .red, .orange, .green, .yellow, .purple]

    var zIndex : Int
    var color : Color
}

class Data: ObservableObject {

    @Published var cards : [Card] = []

    init() {
        for i in 0..<Card.cardColors.count {
            cards.append(Card(intID: i, zIndex: i, color: Card.cardColors[i]))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var data : Data = Data()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                CardView().environmentObject(data)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
     //   .position(x: 370, y: 300)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var data : Data

    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State var dragging:Bool = false
    @State var tapped:Bool = false
    @State var tappedLocation:Int = -1
    @State var locationDragged:Int = -1
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                ForEach((0..<self.data.cards.count), id: \.self) { i in
                    ColorCard(card: self.data.cards[i], reader:reader, offset: self.$offset, tappedLocation: self.$tappedLocation, locationDragged:self.$locationDragged, tapped: self.$tapped, dragging: self.$dragging, i: i)
                        .environmentObject(self.data)
                        .zIndex(Double(self.data.cards[i].zIndex))
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.spring())
    }
}

struct ColorCard: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var data : Data

    var card: Card

    var reader: GeometryProxy
    @State var offsetHeightBeforeDragStarted: Int = 0
    @Binding var offset: CGSize
    @Binding var tappedLocation:Int
    @Binding var locationDragged:Int
    @Binding var tapped:Bool
    @Binding var dragging:Bool
    @State var i: Int
    @State var numTimesCalledSinceDragBegan: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                VStack {
                    card.color
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
                .cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 20)
                .offset(
                    x: (self.numTimesCalledSinceDragBegan <= 1 && self.locationDragged == card.intID) ? CGFloat(card.zIndex) * self.offset.width / 14
                        : 0,
                    y: (self.numTimesCalledSinceDragBegan <= 1 && self.locationDragged == card.intID) ? CGFloat(card.zIndex) * self.offset.height / 4
                        : 0
                )
                    .offset(
                        x: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation != card.intID) ? 100 : 0,
                        y: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation != card.intID) ? 0 : 0
                )
                    .position(x: reader.size.width / 2, y: (self.tapped && self.tappedLocation == card.intID) ? -(cardSpace * CGFloat(card.zIndex)) + 0 : reader.size.height / 2)
            }
//            .rotationEffect(
//                (card.zIndex % 2 == 0) ? .degrees(-0.2 * Double(arc4random_uniform(15)+1) ) : .degrees(0.2 * Double(arc4random_uniform(15)+1) )
//            )

//                .onTapGesture() { //Show the card
//                    self.tapped.toggle()
//                    self.tappedLocation = self.card.intID
//
//            }

                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.numTimesCalledSinceDragBegan += 1

                            self.locationDragged = self.card.intID
                            self.offset = gesture.translation

                            if(self.numTimesCalledSinceDragBegan == 1) {
                                if let index = self.data.cards.firstIndex(of: self.card) {
                                    if(self.offset.height >= 0) {self.i += 1 } else {self.i -= 1}
                                    self.data.cards.remove(at: index)
                                    self.data.cards.insert(self.card, at:

                                        (self.offset.height >= 0) ?  self.i :  self.i
                                    )


                                    for index in 0..<self.data.cards.count {
                                        self.data.cards[index].zIndex = index
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            self.dragging = true
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        self.locationDragged = -1 //Reset
                        self.offset = .zero
                        self.dragging = false
                        self.tapped = false //enable drag to dismiss
                        self.offsetHeightBeforeDragStarted = Int(self.offset.height)
                        self.numTimesCalledSinceDragBegan = 0
                    }
            )
        }.offset(y: (cardSpace * CGFloat(card.zIndex)))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(Data())
    }
}
```